# XSLT applay-template mode="@attr"

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

is it possible to apply a template to an attribute?
I write an XSL which prints out addresses in the right order regarding to the country the address is from. So for example:

Australia:

```
Honorific FirstName LastName
CompanyName
.
.
```

Brazil:

```
CompanyName
Honorific FirstName LastName
```

my XML looks like:

```
<Addresses locale="AUS">
<Address>
    <Honorific/>
    <FirstName/>
    <LastName/>
    <CompanyName>Name of the Company</CompanyName>
    <CompanyName2/>
    <Address1>Mainstreet 17</Address1>
    <Address2/>
    <PostalCode>59943</PostalCode>
    <City>Somewhere</City>
    <City2/>
    <District/>
    <State/>
</Address>
```

My XML is generated ot of a database so depending on the country I choose I'll get 0 to X addresses. And cause there are arround 30 different ways to write an Address (in different countries), I have to apply a template to every possible locale. Like:

```
<xsl:template match="/Addresses">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test=" @locale='PH' ">
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="PH" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test=" @locale='AUS' ">
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="AUS" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="#default" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

My question now, is there a way to say:

```
<xsl:apply-templates mode="@locale">
```

?

or store the locale in a variable and put that in my mode..

Thanks!

Comment: It's not possible to make `mode` a dynamic parameter. If you want to have a template for each locale, I suggest you reconsider the answer given by @dlask below, perhaps with the correction suggested by me in the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about individual templates?

```
<xsl:template match="/Addresses[@locale='PH']">
   ...
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/Addresses[@locale='AUS']">
   ...
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/Addresses">
   ... the default one ...
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi, I have different templates for every possible country. It's just about the selector in my apply-templates.. so now I have 30 templates and need now 30 xsl:when to test the locale.. perfect would be a apply-templates where it reads the locale so i dont need the 30 whens

Comment: You should make the templates `match="Address[../@locale='PH']"` etc.